# CIRCUITPY on RP2040 Won't Reboot and Run code.py

Tags: boot, hardware, reboot, circuitpython

I'm trying to build this [T9 Macro Pad](https://github.com/dupontgu/t9-macropad-circuitpython) project, by Guy Dupont, using a PIMORONI TINY2040, which uses a RP2040 chip.

I installed CircuitPython 6.3.0 on the development board and then could see the RP2040 drive available as CIRCUITPY under volumes on my computer. At this point, I included the [recommended libraries](https://github.com/dupontgu/t9-macropad-circuitpython/tree/main/fw/tiny2040) in the board's lib directory:

> - adafruit_hid adafruit_hid/__init__.mpy
>
>   - adafruit_hid/consumer_control_code.mpy
>   - adafruit_hid/consumer_control.mpy
>   - adafruit_hid/keyboard_layout_us.mpy
>   - adafruit_hid/keyboard.mpy
>   - adafruit_hid/keycode.mpy
>   - adafruit_hid/mouse.mpy
> - adafruit_matrixkeypad.mpy

This file was meant to be part of the directory structure, but it wasn't included in the libraries that I downloaded:

> - adafruit_hid/gamepad.mpy

After setting up the lib structure, I tried to follow the steps under [the firmware section of the guide](https://github.com/dupontgu/t9-macropad-circuitpython/tree/main/fw), to prepare the firmware for deployment on the board. Finally, I copied the files, bar README.md, from the [TINY2040 directory](https://github.com/dupontgu/t9-macropad-circuitpython/tree/main/fw/tiny2040) onto the CIRCUITPY drive.

As I understand it, the board should have reboot at this point to run the code.py file. My issue is that the board just stays connected as a CIRCUITPY drive. I have tried, and have not been able, to get the board to reboot and start running code.py

I'd really appreciate any suggestions you have on how to get the board to run the code. If there's anything that seems out of the usual, or that I may have done correctly, above please don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: I assume the Pico is on topic.  I'm not sure if we can hope to support every device incorporating the RP2040.

Comment: @joan that’s fair enough, I don’t expect this place to cover everything. I can remove the post if you see fit. I asked as I though the issue was the processor, and therefore no different to Circuit Python on a Pico.

Comment: It's just a comment by a standard member.  It's up to the moderators to decide if a question is off topic or not.  The closer your environment is to a Pico the more likely someone here can answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The gamepad library was recently deprecated for the keypad_matrix library due to a number of factors. There is a new guide on how to use the new guide on learn.adafruit.com